# MySQL/ASP - Confusing SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, asp-classic

I have a celebrity photo website, 100,000 photos and growing. The user has made a search "Oscar Awards Ceremony" and I currently loop through the results to display the relevant photos.

Now, I'd like to offer a search refinement column, that sits beside the results, that will show specific names of the people that were photographed at that particular event (based on photoID's from results), showing the quantity of photos next each name and displaying the names in order of highest quantity.

Like so:

---

**You searched for:** "Oscar Awards Ceremony" (12,489)

**Specific People:**

Brad Pitt (1,726)

Angelina Jolie (1,302)

Edward Norton (929)...

---

This is my database schema:

```
photoSearch (tbl)
photoID             INT(11)         Index       Auto-Increment
headline            VarChar(1000)   FullText
caption             VarChar(2500)   FullText
dateCreated         DateTime        Index

photoPeople (tbl)
photoID             INT(11)
peopleID            INT(11)

people (tbl)
peopleID            INT(11)         Primary     Auto-Increment
people              VarChar(255)    Index
```

So basically, I have a result set of photoID's from the users last search. Using that result set, I need to query the 'photoPeople' and 'people' table, to list the people that are related to those photoID's, I need to show the quantity and to order them by quantity.

How can I go about doing this? Can it be done in one query? Will I have to write the results in to a table to be able to count and order them?

This is what I have done so far but only lists peoples names:

```
SELECT * FROM people
INNER JOIN photopeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
WHERE photoID IN ('87345','8900','83458','63746')
```

I'm not looking for exact code, although it would be very helpful, I'm just looking for advice on how to accomplish this correctly with performance in-mind. I think my brain is capable of showing the relevant people, but not in any order and certainly without a count!

Any help gratefully received...

P.S. When I get a working solution together, I will apply this to my events table and keywords too. This means if somebody searched "Brad Pitt", the event "Oscar Awards Ceremony" will appear in the 'refine search' column, with 1,726 next to the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF I understand your schema correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT people.People AS Name, count(*) AS NumberOfPhotos 
FROM people
INNER JOIN photoPeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
WHERE photoPeople.photoID IN ('87345','8900','83458','63746')
GROUP BY photoPeople.PeopleID, people.People
ORDER BY NumberOfPhotos DESC
```

(Sorry, I'm more familiar with MSSQL, but I assume MySql is very similar)

Comment: Thanks. Funny that, I was just experimenting with an idea I had too and both are very similar, mine works and so does yours:

SELECT COUNT(people) AS totalPeople, people
FROM people
INNER JOIN photopeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
WHERE photoid IN ('87345','8900','83458','63746','82039','53696','53697','53698')
GROUP BY people
ORDER BY totalPeople DESC

Comment: Plus I'm only showing the top 5 names at that event with counts, so performance will be okay with this I think...

Comment: Yeah, no worries. One further comment.. if you already have stored the query results (i.e. the photo IDs) in another table, then better to JOIN to that table, rather than using an IN statement.

Comment: I haven't stored the results anywhere. I select the photoID, headline, caption and dateCreated, as that is what's displayed with the photos and doing a 'do while not loop' I display the photos. Do you suggest storing the photoID's?

Comment: Or is using IN painfully slow?

Comment: Depends on how many results you are expecting for a search. I know that IN has certain performance implications in MSSQL.  It will probably come down to how the query optimizer treats your query, which you'd need to profile.

Comment: Cool thanks. I will read up about this and see how I can efficiently query those ID's. For your information, one search like 'black' could return 51,853 right now. In 12 months time, it could jump to 100,000+

Comment: mmm.. this has brought on a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is outside of the sql query, but look into solr and faceting... you can do a search, then refine by facets. You also get neat functions like autocomplete, spell check, and stemming.